# Alexa App Express missing OutputSpeech in response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, response, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build an alexa app with the npm package "alexa-app". I have written the following Intent.

```
alexaApp.intent("MyIntent", {
    "slots": {},
    "utterances": ["Tell me a quote"]
},
function(request, response) {

    req('http://exampleUrl.com', function (error, res, body) {
        if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(body);
            var message = obj.value;
            response.say(message);

        }
    });


});
```

When I test my Skill the outputSpeech is missing and the service response looks like this. Getting the data from the url works.

`{
 "version": "1.0",
 "response": {
 "shouldEndSession": true
 },
 "sessionAttributes": {}
 }`

If I try to use response.say() in the outer function I will get the correct service response like this but of course without the message. Can anybody help me please, to return the correct service response with my message?

`{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak></speak>"
    },
    "shouldEndSession": true
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
response.send();
```

after

`response.say(message);`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using Promises.